# Portable way to parse local date/time (with implicit time zone)

Tags: java, android, datetime, parsing, timezone

I need to parse strings containing local date and time. The time zone is not explicitly specified, but the timestamps are in local time for a particular place.

Challenges are:

- I need to be compatible with Java 7, which rules out a bunch of nifty features introduces with Java 8.
- Java 7 compatibility is mostly needed for older Android versions, but the code will run on both JRE and Android.
- Times are either in standard time or DST, depending on the time of the year. Hence a simple UTC offset will not work, as it jumps back and forward by an hour per year.

(This also means that timestamps during the DST to standard time switchover are ambiguous, but I can live with an hour of inaccuracy for that particular corner case.)

Here’s how far I got:

```
/*
 * Let timestampString be the date/time string, examples:
 * "2023-01-28 20:36"
 * "2022-07-07 13:37"
 */
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm zzzz");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(timestampString + " CET");
System.out.println("Timestamp: " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

Problem: this interprets everything as Central European Standard time, all year round – during the summer season, times are off by one hour.

Using a time zone name such as `Europe/Brussels` instead of `CET` (which works with `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZonedDateTime` on Java 8) does not work, as the string is not recognized.

Does Java 7 offer anything comparable? (Preferably without having to resort to external libraries.)

Comment: *I need to be compatible with Java 7, which rules out a bunch of nifty features introduces with Java 8.* Not really true. Use [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and java.time, the modern Java date and time API. *Preferably without having to resort to external libraries* Technically the backport is an external library, but its the code that is working in Java 8, so not really that external. It’s rock solid, and it will prepare you well for the day when you can let go of Java 7 and upgrade to a more modern Java version.

Comment: @OleV.V. I am aware of that, but IIRC this is a particular pain when Android is involved. This is why I want to steer clear of external dependencies, and in particular of ThreeTen Backport.

Comment: Is Android your only pain? If so, use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). If desktop Java 7 is also in scope, I understand that using the backport gets more complicated since there is a separate Android adaptation, but shouldn’t you be able to manage? I’d personally go to great lengths for that.

Comment: Still a lot of overhead for that particular use case when there is a much simpler solution, see my answer.

Comment: Your answer is a step forward in relation to the code in the question. But its still a solution pointing backward in time. If your code is to be maintained beyond February this year, you should prefer a solution that points forward. Meaning forgetting about the notorious troublesome date-time classes from the mid-1990s. Just my 0.02$.

Comment: The legacy date-time classes are terribly flawed, designed by people who did not understand date-time handling. You *really* should reconsider your objection to using the modern classes. The little bit of effort to either add the back-port library, or to learn API desugaring in Android, is well worth it to avoid the old classes. The old classes really are that bad.

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse("2022-07-07 13:37", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm zzzz", Locale.FRENCH))`. Yields `2022-07-07 13:37 heure d’été d’Europe centrale`. Split up into more statements and substitute your desired locale.

Comment: Also the code is exactly the same when you use ThreeTen Backport for JRE 7 and ThreeTenABP for Android. The only difference will be the need to initialize the library once on Android. The imported packages and classes are the same and are named the same. While I do myself hesitate to commit to external dependencies, I really can’t see the big deal in this particular case.

Comment: All right, you guys convinced me :-) desktop Java is not the issue, it’s only Android that needs the workaround (as, sadly, it takes Google three years to adopt a new Java API). Took me a while to set it up, but it’s an investment with future benefits. I’ve updated the answer to include both options, with their pros and cons. Just out of interest, anyone have a pointer to a description of the bugs in the Java 7-style classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two general options:

#### Option 1: Use Java 8+ classes, with API desugaring on Android

**Pros:** Future proof; does not suffer from the bugs in Java’s `Date` and related classes; gives you [a number of Java 8 APIs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)

**Cons:** Will work on Android prior to API 26 (Android 8) but not on JRE7; may require toolchain upgrades (which you will eventually need to do anyway)

This is the preferred way at least if you don’t have to support old desktop Java versions. Java 8 support on Android (at least in part) is done through a process called [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring).

First, make sure you are at least on Gradle 6.1.1 and version 4.0.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.

Your `build.gradle` should not specify a `buildToolsVersion` unless you need a specific one (which then needs to be 29.0.2 or higher).

Then add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.8'
}
```

Version 1.1.8 [is equivalent to 1.2.2](https://github.com/google/desugar_jdk_libs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) (which is the version Google recommends as of January 2023) but works on older versions of the R8/D8 compiler (I got an error with 1.2.2 but 1.1.8 worked).

All the changes so far only apply to the Android build. For other platforms you may be running the code on, nothing changes.

This allows you to then run the following Java code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    .withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels"));
try {
    ZonedDateTime zonedDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(rawDate, formatter);
    System.out.println("Timestamp: " + zonedDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm zzzz")))
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    // do whatever is necessary here
}
```

If you need to pass this to something that expects a `Date`, you can convert that using `Date.from(zonedDate.toInstant())`.

#### Option 2: Use Java 7-compatible classes

**Pros:** Works on any Java 7 API, whether desktop or Android

**Cons:** Not future proof (as you are using deprecated classes); still suffers from all the bugs in Java’s `Date` and related classes; will solve this particular API incompatibility but not others

`DateFormat` has a `setTimeZone()` method, which accepts a `TimeZone` argument (which, in turn, can be generated from a string such as `Europe/Brussels`). Setting it will cause date/time strings to be parsed as local time in that time zone, with automatic adjustment for DST. No need to append anything to the string being parsed.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Brussels"));
Date date = dateFormat.parse(timestampString);
/*
 * dateFormat no longer contains a time zone, so use a separate format
 * for output (with the time zone)
 */
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm zzzz");
dateFormatOut.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Brussels"));
System.out.println("Timestamp: " + dateFormatOut.format(date));
```